# DBAccess: long long value supprted or not?

Tags: ios, objective-c, dbaccess

I'm using dbaccess for my project. I want to know, Is dbaccess supported long long value or not?

```
 If I stored date timestamp 745665352687 than if I retrieved it, it returns -1572180756.
```

I know sqlite supports long long value, but don't know about dbaccess. Can anyone help me? Thanx in adv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, long long is one of the supported types.  I've looked into the problem, and all versions should work fine for your example above.

I've created a class and assigned your example value.

```
@interface Test : DBObject

@property long long value;

@end
```

Output:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Entity : Test                          Primary Key : Id       Value: 1.000000           |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Field Name         |  Type        |                  Value                              |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id                 | NUMBER       | 1.000000                                            |
| value              | NUMBER       | 745665352687.000000                                 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Relationships                                                                           |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Entity Name         |  Target Table     |                  Status                       |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| NONE                |                   |                                               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I've then tested the output and it is correct.  I suspect your problem may lay elsewhere in the implementation.

For information, these are the data types supported by DBAccess:

```
NSNumber
NSString
UIImage / NSImage
NSArray
NSDictionary
NSDate
int
BOOL
long
float
char
short
long long
unsigned char
unsigned int
unsigned short
unsigned long
unsigned long long
double
char*
NSURL
NSData
NSMutableData
NSMutableArray
NSMutableDictionary
NSObject // (provided it implements an NSKeyedArchiver)
int64
unsigned int64
```