# Issue - DBAccess ORM create table with declare bool type with swift

Tags: ios, swift, orm, dbaccess, dbobject

i am facing issue with create table in DBObject (DBAccess ORM) with declare **bool** type and **Int** type field, and also i am not able to declare "description" filed.

//Swift Code:-

import UIKit

@objc(Circlelist)

class Circlelist: DBObject {

```
dynamic var name : String!;
dynamic var group_id : NSNumber!;
dynamic var group_id : Int!;   //Getting issue here
dynamic var desc : String!;
dynamic var description : String!; //Getting issue here
dynamic var address : String!;
dynamic var latitude : String!;
dynamic var longitude : String!;
var isdeleted : Bool = false;    //Getting issue here
```

}

When i wright "**dynamic var isdeleted : Bool!;**" at that time give error like "*Property cannot be marked dynamic because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C*".

[image: dynamic var isdeleted : Bool!]

and when i wright "**dynamic var isdeleted : Bool;**" at that time give error like "*Class circle list has no initialiser*".

[image: dynamic var isdeleted : Bool]

Please suggest me perfect solution to know how to fix this issue, give details about DataType and more information about DBAccess.

Comment: please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help)it will be useful to lift your content quality up

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify what issues you are getting exactly, but some of them I can guess.

```
dynamic var description : String!;
```

**description** is a method name on Objective-C classes, so it is a reserved word.  The compiler is warning you of this.

```
dynamic var group_id : Int!;
```

`Int!` is not a supported type in Obj-C, as the compiler error is telling you.  So you will need to use NSNumber.

```
var isdeleted : Bool = false;
```

I'm not clear what the issue might be, except the absence of the dynamic keyword to indicate it's persistence.

See this SO article to see a list of supported Objective-C types.

[DBAccess: long long value supprted or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29793459/dbaccess-long-long-value-supprted-or-not?answertab=active#tab-top)

If you have more information about the issues you are having then please add it and we will try to help further.

Comment: Hi Adrian_H..!!.. Thanks for your feedback.

When i wright  "dynamic var isdeleted : Bool!;" at that time give error like 
"Property cannot be marked dynamic because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C"


and when i wright "dynamic var isdeleted : Bool;" at that time give error like Class circle list has no initialiser.

Please give your feedback.

Comment: If you remove the "!" and assign it a default value it will be compatible with ObjC.  ```dynamic var isdeleted : Bool = false```, DBAccess will then replace it's value when read from the tables.  You will then no longer get the compilation errors about your class missing initialisers.